# add custom field template to theme admin page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

in WP admin how to add the custom field template plugin to a theme page?

it automatically shows in posts and pages but i want this in the theme page. the theme am using is from iwak "creations" portfolio page.

what files do i need to modify to add this?

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to say what you need to modify without being able to look at the code.  Being a premium theme, we can't just download it and take a look.

Having said that, the theme may use the WordPress [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types) functionality.  Search the code for a call to the [register_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) function.  If it's used, you may be in luck.  Either

- add 'custom-fields' to the `supports` argument in that call, or
- call [add_post_type_support](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support) after the post type is registered.  The `$post_type` parameter will be the first value passed to the `register_post_type` function, and the `$supports` parameter will be 'custom-fields'.

Comment: thanks for your reply Hobo, but am still unsure on this il have to read more on this custom post type..  its the admin page i want to have an extra field but i have no idea what file is used or even how to add this!

Comment: wish that plugin had automatically added the fields!

Answer (score 1):

Daniel, are you using this Custom Post Type Plugin - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/screenshots/? I've used it before, and the guy who created it is Japanese, so his personal page isn't very useful as far as support for english goes.

I had some trouble with this at first. But what I think you're trying to do is add the custom fields to your new pages you've created, correct?

It's not very straightforward, but once it works it's pretty awesome.

Basically, when you set up the plugin you create these different "Custom fields," right? Well part of that should look like this:

```
[Custom Field Name]
type = textarea
rows = 4
cols = 40
tinyMCE = true
htmlEditor = true
```

Ok, so once you've created those "Custom fields" keep note of the part in brackets. You'll add this to your template pages:

`<?php getCustomField('Custom Field Name'); ?>`

Now when you enter the info in the pages or posts, the content should appear as you've entered it.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thats is the right plugin i was on about but i could not get it to work in the admin page not the template page itself. i have now figured it out and you use the "Custom Post Type (comma-deliminated)" which is in the plugin options page, you need to say which template ie the template name.